# Javascript approach to copy properties of first array(of objects) into another array(of objects) of different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array say

```
srcObj = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}]

destObj = [{a:1, b:2}]
```

I want to copy values of this array into another array that may have a shorter length than the above srcObj array. How would I construct the loop to increase the length of destObj array depending on the size of srcObj array and then insert the missing items from srcObj array to destObj array.

Comment: `destObj.length = srcObj.length` ?

Comment: Does the destination array hold references to the same objects that are in the source, or are they duplicate objects that have all the same property names and values?

Comment: They are duplicate objects that has property names that match the source object. It may have additional property names too..

Answer (score 0):

The following code do the job:

```js
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(list[i]) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var srcObj = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}]
var destObj = [{a:1, b:2}]

for(var i = 0; i < srcObj.length; i++) {
 if (!containsObject(srcObj[i], destObj)){
   destObj.push(srcObj[i]);
  }
}
console.log(destObj);
```

If you want a more slow and more generic way to compare objects I recommend you to read the answer for the question: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Mostly correct, just that when you do `destObj.push(srcObj[i]);` is it pushing the reference to object or the new object?

Comment: How can I also assign values of srcObj into destObj for matching properties(or keys)?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming destObj.length < srcObj.length is already known)

Maybe:

```
var i;
while ((i = destObj.length) < srcObj.length) {
  destObj.push(srcObj[i]);
}
```

?

(But note it's just a shallow copy of array items, from srcObj into destObj; the "copied" object values will be in fact shared by the two arrays, by references; and this may or may not be what you want)